# vertical progress bar cannot be assigned to end of the layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-progressbar, exoplayer2.x

I'm trying to implement vertical progress bar. But the progress bar doesn't seems to be moving to right end of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/idGestureContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".zzzz_dummy.GestureEvents">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/determinateBar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"
        android:rotation="270"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Kindly anyone help me on moving this pregress bar to start and end of the view. I need both, one for volume and one for brightness. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok one thing you can do is wrap it.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" // for left
        // app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" // for right
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/idVolumeControl"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="50"
            android:rotation="270" />

    </FrameLayout>
```